# Map two dataframes using pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tomm', 2, 11111, 2548],
                    ['matt', 2, 158416, 2483],
                    ['tonmmm', 2, 11111, 2549]
                    ], columns=["name", "cell", "marks", "passwd"])
```

**Input**

df1

```
    name    cell        marks
0   tom       2         11111
```

df2

```
    name    cell    marks   passwd
0   tomm    2      11111     2548
1   matt    2      158416    2483
2   tonmmm  2      11111     2549
```

map two dataframe which has similar columns

get columns from df2 which has match atleast a count of 2. here `cell` and `marks` matches with df1 with 2 values

**expected output:**

```
    name    cell    marks   passwd
0   tomm    2      11111     2548
1   tonmmm  2      11111     2549
```

Comment: How do you define similar ?

Comment: Are you looking for cases where marks are equal?

Comment: @Hugolmn get columns from df2 which has match atleast a count of 2. here `cell` and `marks` matches with df1 with 2 values

Comment: @NYCCoder get columns from df2 which has match atleast a count of 2. here `cell` and `marks` matches with df1 with 2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tomm', 2, 11111, 2548],
                    ['matt', 2, 158416, 2483],
                    ['tonmmm', 2, 11111, 2549]
                    ], columns=["name", "cell", "marks", "passwd"])

temp=[len([i for i in list(row)[1:] if i in list(df1.iloc[0,:])])>=2 for row in df2[df2.columns[:len(df2.columns)-1]].to_records()]
newdf=df2[temp]
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
     name  cell  marks  passwd
0    tomm     2  11111    2548
2  tonmmm     2  11111    2549
```

**Edit**: In the case you want to sort it base on the number of matches, you could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks"])  
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tomm', 2, 11111, 2548],['matt', 2, 158416, 2483], ['tom', 2, 11111, 2549]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks", "passwd"])
temp=[len([i for i in list(row)[1:] if i in list(df1.iloc[0,:])]) for row in df2[df2.columns[:len(df2.columns)-1]].to_records()]
newdf=df2.copy().assign(val=temp).sort_values(by='val',ascending=False)
mask=np.where(newdf.val.ge(2), True, False)
newdf=newdf.drop(['val'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)[mask]
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   name  cell  marks  passwd
0   tom     2  11111    2549
1  tomm     2  11111    2548
```

Comment: i tried using this `df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 2, 11111]], columns=["name", "cell", "marks"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tomm', 2, 11111, 2548],
                    ['matt', 2, 158416, 2483],
                    ['tom', 2, 11111, 2549]
                    ], columns=["name", "cell", "marks", "passwd"])`   


there are three values  matching in one case. it should be returned as first. how to modify it to get it in  descending order of values

Comment: I just edited the answer for that case @somara4935. Hope it works for you! If you found it helpful, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) :)!